# Как правильно разделить на строки этот отрывок из моего стихотворения?

Tags: поэзия

Как правильно разделить на строки этот отрывок из моего стихотворения?

1. > Не зная: дружбá — вот что настояще цéнно,

> Вот чем надо дорожить.

2. > Не зная:

> Дружбá —

> Вот что настояще цéнно,

> Вот чем надо дорожить.

P. S. Второй вариант показывает паузы. Я просто даже и не знаю, можно ли строчку стиха из одного едиственного слова делать.

Comment: Вы у Маяковского посмотрите:  https://www.culture.ru/poems/21383/khorosho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Разделим текст на **фонетические** слова, их надо произносить с одним ударением. В качестве варианта:

   ```
   Не зная, 

   дрУжба —  

   вОт что 

   по-настоящему цЕнно,

   вОт чем 

   надо дорожИть.
   ```

[О лесенке Маковского](https://proza.ru/2019/10/24/1479)

2. А это современный пример деления на строки песни **«Я» в стиле рэп**  (мой вариант). В этом стиле ударение делается  практически на каждом слове (бить словом), но фразовое ударение тоже нужно. (Но эта строфа записывается и обычным текстом.)  **[Вариант записи](https://tekst-pesni.online/dajte-tank-lyudi/)**

   ```
   Я всегда  стараюсь  быть
   хорошим,
   Даже за глаза  никого
   не оскорблю,
   Даже мнение чужое  уважаю,
   предположим,
   Да только я никого 
   не люблю.
   ```

https://yandex.ru/video/preview/13718992627362939713